# Java code, array/matrix component

Tags: java, arrays

I have this 3x1 array/matrix in java. How can i use any one of the single components of the array. Lets say i want to

```
r = Math.pow(second row component,2) + Math.pow(third row component,2)
```

What is the calling code for the components?
Thanks

Comment: If i have a 3 by 1 matrix, i want to take the sum of the squares of the second component and the third component of the matrix?

Comment: That's almost exactly what your question says. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach to iterate through the array, and then add Math.Pow index by index

```
double[] myArray = { 1.2, 16.5, 20.0 }
double r = 0;
for(double d : myArray)
{
    r+= Math.pow(d,2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by components you mean `elements`, then the syntax is as follows:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};

int num = numbers[0];

System.out.println("Number: " + num);

// Outputs Number: 1
```

**Extra Reading**

You should read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). This contains all of the information you need to use the array type in Java.

Comment: Hi yes by components i mean elements. But i want to use these elements for calculations. Not just display them.

Comment: So put `numbers[0]` inside of a calculation. `int n = numbers[0] + numbers[1];`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an element of an array, apend the index of the element in brackets:

```
r = Math.pow(second row component,2) + Math.pow(third row component,2)
```

becomes

```
r = Math.pow(arrayVariable[1],2) + Math.pow(arrayVariable[2],2)
```

Remember, array indexes are base zero.

Comment: Hi thanks. Just one more. It says The method pow(double, double) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (double[], int). Can you please suggest something?